# How to compute the pixel size and beam size in a fits file?

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy, fits

I can't see the beam size in the header. How to find it?

Comment: should be in the headers, http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/#working-with-fits-headers

Comment: The beam size is not in the header

Comment: Then have to get it from instrument

Answer (score 1):

The beam size should be in the FITS header in the keywords `BMAJ`, `BMIN`, and `BPA`.  In some cases, e.g. for files produced with AIPS or early versions of CASA, these keywords may be missing but the beam information is still included somewhere in the `HISTORY` keywords.  The [`radio-beam`](https://github.com/radio-astro-tools/radio_beam) package is intended to extract this information:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from radio_beam import beam

header = fits.getheader(filename)
beam = Beam.from_fits_header(header)
print(beam)
```